# Teradata Multi load Not Proceed

Tags: teradata, utility, mload

mload step

1. .LOGTABLE truser2.logtable;
2. .LOGON 127.0.0.1/truser2,trpass2;
3. .begin import mload tables coldata_test
   WORKTABLES wt_test1
   ERRORTABLES wt_test1 uv_test1
   ERRLIMIT 1000
   CHECKPOINT 100000
   AMPCHECK NONE;
4. .layout test_layout;
   .field col01 * varchar(255);
   .field col02 * varchar(255);
   .field col03 * varchar(255);
5. .DML LABEL test_insert
6. IGNORE MISSING UPDATE ROWS
7. DO INSERT FOR MISSING UPDATE ROWS;
8. UPDATE coldata_test SET col02 =:col02
           ,col03 = :col03
       where col01 = :col01;
9. insert into coldata_test
       values(
           :col01,
           :col02,
           :col03);
10. .IMPORT INFILE /home/tdatuser/bin/data2.dat
    LAYOUT test_layout FORMAT VARTEXT ','
    APPLY test_insert;
11. .END MLOAD;
12. .LOGOFF;

data2.dat : abdfe,aasf,xxcvf

result : This MultiLoad import task cannot proceed: an unexpected
     MultiLoad phase, data acquisition, was reported by the RDBMS.

what is problem??

Comment: Can you add the full output? Might be due to a restart.

Comment: So a `SELECT 1 FROM coldata_test;` yields an error message, correct? To @dnoeth's point, the a previous MultiLoad may have aborted in acquisition phase. Were the work tables for this MulitLoad dropped before the MultiLoad was restarted and completed successfully?